# Python split and manipulate results

Tags: python, string, split

What is the pythonic way of code below, which was basically copied from php?

```
def get_extra_info(self, info):
    extra = []
    for i in info.split(';'):
        t = i.split(':')
        extra[t[0]] = t[1]
    return extra
```

Info is in following format

```
info = "test:1;xxx:4;yyy:12"
```

Comment: Presumably you meant for `extra` to be a *dictionary*, not a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a generator expression with the [`dict()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dict):

```
return dict(item.split(':', 1) for item in info.split(';'))
```

This makes use of the fact that the `dict()` function accepts an iterable of `(key, value)` pairs. The `1` argument to `str.split()` limits the splitting to just once; more efficient and any extra `:` colons are ignored and become part of the value.

Demo:

```
>>> info = "test:1;xxx:4;yyy:12"
>>> dict(item.split(':', 1) for item in info.split(';'))
{'test': '1', 'xxx': '4', 'yyy': '12'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you use extra as a dictionary. Indexing a list by string is no possible. So do like this:

```
def get_extra_info(self, info):
    extra = {}
    for i in info.split(';'):
        t = i.split(':')
        extra[t[0]] = t[1]
    return extra
```